Use MOSFET to drive a high current source from a low-current digital logic output
I'm a beginner hobbyist here, and I'm in a bit over my head with MOSFET transistors. I want to control a fan with a microprocessor, and since it pulls more current than a digital I/O pin can drive, I thought I could use a logic level coming from the processor to control power from the power supply circuitry. I used this circuit:

My thoughts were that driving FAN to logic low would give the attached fan a low resistance circuit with ground, and driving FAN to logic high would make this very highly resistive. Note that Vcc is 5 V and FAN logic high is 3.3 V. Also note that J9 was an escape hatch 0hm resistor footprint and is not placed.
I had this board made, and it does not work like I'd hoped. The potential difference over the fan pins is around 5 V always, though it did seem like slightly less when FAN was high. Can someone help me understand where I went wrong and how to do this? If Vcc was 3.3 V, would this have worked as I'd hoped?
MOSFET datasheet

you need to use an nchannel mosfet in the sink position like that.

It needs an Nch Vt<= 1.5V RdsOn <= 0.1 Ohm.  Pch source must be more positive than drain for a high side switch but then you would need 10 ~ 12V to turn off on gate for Vg.

If you are driving the MOSFET from a low level logic signal then you should look for transistors described as "logic level". They are specifically designed to switch reliably with the sort of logic levels most common micros put out.

Please draw your schematics (where possible) to conform with (1) Higher potentials nearer the top, and (2) signals flow from left (input) to right (output). These are the only two MOSFET and load configurations which will work as you expected:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Both are connected common-source, and both have \$V_{GS(TH)} \approx 1V\$.
On the left is a P-channel MOSFET, switching at the high side. These are gate potentials \$V_{IN}\$ necessary to switch the fan on and off:

ON: \$V_{IN} << (+5V-1V)\$
OFF: \$V_{IN} >> (+5V-1V)\$

On the right I use an N-channel transistor:

ON: \$V_{IN} >> +1V\$
OFF: \$V_{IN} << +1V\$

Notice that the P-channel version requires a low input to switch on, the inverse of the N-channel design which requires a high input to switch on.
Notice also that I used the symbols \$<<\$ and \$>>\$, indicating significantly less than or greater than, respectively. You must avoid the condition where \$V_{GS} \approx V_{GS(TH)}\$, since this will place the MOSFET channel in a partially conductive state, neither fully on nor fully off.
The N-channel design will work with a 0V/+3.3V input, but the P-channel design will not. An input of +3.3V is insufficient to turn it off, and in fact you would require close to +5V at the gate to reliably switch it off, which is why your fan is always powered.
This is because the state of a MOSFET's channel (its on/off state) is determined by the potential difference between its gate and source, \$V_{GS}=V_G-V_S\$. Those two designs have different \$V_S\$. For the common-source N-channel arrangement (right), \$V_S=0V\$, whereas the P-channel's source (left) is connected to \$V_S=+5V\$. Subtle, but critical.
Also, don't forget diode D1/D2, which protects the transistor by suppressing the large voltage spikes that occur when an inductive load is switched off.

The diode in the PMOS between the terminals 2 and 3 will keep the pin 2 always low. You need an NMOS like mentioned in the comments by others.
